# Delete statement does not execute in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I read the similar issue shared on stack overflow regarding `DELETE` command is not execute a query.

I am a beginner level on SQL and was trying to understand identity column action so I created a super basic `studentinfo` table and put `firstname`, `lastname`, and `id` columns.

ID selected as identity column and incremental is setup 5. That is the summary of the table. And created couple rows for the table.

Now when I execute `DELETE FROM StudentInfo WHERE StudentId like '0213422'` returns `0 rows affected` and of course not deleting that row.

Anyone tell why is that happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It ID is incremental:5, how come you expect to have such an id: 0213422?? BTW, there is no row with the ID: 0213422 in the table. Also, please try DELETE FROM StudentInfo WHERE StudentId like '0213422%'

Comment: @ErayBalkanli This not real application for any client. Just playing around so any reason to change studentid and incremental setup. By the way I added couple rows to table. I will update the above statement. Tesekkurler :)

Comment: Dont use `Like`, use ` = `  instead

Comment: @JoakimDanielson. Thanks that worked. Sorry for very simple question

Comment: Are you SURE you have ID set up as an IDENTITY column? If so, values would never start with a text "0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use:

```
where StudentId like '%0213422%'
```

or

```
where StudentId = '0213422'
```

[Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can be used with placeholders like '%' or '_'

'%' - indicates that there could be multiple characters in the placeholder.

'_' - indicates that there is exactly one character as a placeholder

### ID | Stuff

1 | Foobar

2 | Fobar

```
where Stuff like 'F%bar' --would return both row

where Stuff like 'F_bar' --would retun only the second row
```

Comment: Actually, `like '0213422'` works the same as `= '0213422'`. It will find just the one with the exact value '0213422'

Comment: Yes but i dont think that like '0213422' is the prefered way to use a "like" clause. I asume he didn't know how Like works, so i explained it

Comment: On that I also agree

Answer (score 0):

Normally an identity column is type bigint or int and contains simply spoken just numbers. So I wonder that a value can have a leading 0.
I suggest to use a select statement first to see, what is in the result set like

```
Select * FROM Studentinfo WHERE StudentId like '%213422'
```

or

```
Select * FROM Studentinfo WHERE StudentId >=213422
```